# Dynamically change the input type using jquery on particular Array,

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to change input type on Array 1, But in result its showing only radio button rest of the checkbox not visible. Please some one help me to fix.

```js
var out="";
$.each($('#shw').children(),function(val,i){
    if(val==1){
      out +='<input type="radio" name="radio" id="rd" >'; 
    }
    $('#shw').html(out);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="shw">
            <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" id="abc" >
            <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox2" id="def" >
            <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox3" id="ghj" >
            <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox4" id="ijk" >
        </div>
```

Comment: what is `val` supposed to be?

Comment: you are assigning only `radio` to `out` variable so `out` variable has the `HTML` only for radio button.

Comment: You need to elaborate more about what you're trying to achieve and how you've gone about trying to achieve it so far.  An explanation of how the code you've provided works could go a long way toward getting a good answer.  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: val i mention for finding array.

Comment: ya your right i assign only radio out. How to show all checkbox and including radio button changes

Answer (score 0):

i don't know what exactly you are trying to achieve, but this should transform the first element to a checkbox by using a counter-variable.
**edit:** and now also output the original element's html for everything else (not tested)

```
var out="";
var counter = 0;
$.each($('#shw').children(),function(val,i){
    counter++;
    if(counter==1){
        out +='<input type="radio" name="radio" id="rd" >'; 
    }else{
        out += $(this).html();
    }

    $('#shw').html(out);
});
```

Comment: Sorry I am new to javascript and jquery, Here i need to show dynamically all checkbox, But wen its reach Index 1 it should change radio button.

Comment: Under ID 4 checkbox are there right, For me when its reach Array 1 it should change radio button on particular Array, In result all checkbox and including radio buttton have to show.